# Blender freezes / hangs when importing FBX exported from Rokoko Studio

Tags: import, .fbx

I am currently trying to import an FBX that has been exported from Rokoko Studio into Blender for retargeting purposes.

The FBX exported from Rokoko Studio opens just fine in Autodesk MotionBuilder, trying to import it to Blender v2.81 or v2.90 (Alpha) causes Blender to freeze and upon clicking into the application window, Windows to tell me that the application does not respond.

I tried changing the exporter to use a different FBX version (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 & 2016), but no matter what, Blender is unable to import it. Due to the freeze, nothing is being written to the Debug Log and importing the Unreal Mannequin FBX works just fine, so I would assume there is something wrong with the files.

But, what could it be? And is this something I can fix or is it up to Rokoko to change the way their exporter works? In a video from [August 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTrh4jPpGfY) they show importing a FBX into Blender 2.8, so I would have assumed there hasn't been much that has changed.

I have uploaded a couple exported files here: [Download via TinyUpload](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=80103333536657910696)

Is there something wrong with the FBX that Rokoko produces?

Comment: do other, arbitrary .fbxs exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: @Kirbinator No, they do not.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the way Blender imports FBX animations. It's extremely unoptimized which can cause long and complex animations (like motion capture ones) to take hours to import. You should use the BVH format with the HumanIK skeleton in the exporter options of Rokoko Studio to export your animation. This format can be imported into Blender quickly without any issues.

[image: Rokoko Studio export options]